QRCompositeReport doesn't match with QRPreviewController
I use QRreport together with QRPreviewController and it works fine. But when I use QRCompositeReport, the QRPreviewController has no effect on the preview of the report.
QReport 6 with Dephi XE7
QRController seems to be inactive in QRCompositeReport.preview.
